# Make <div> element clickable on hover

Tags: html, css, overlay, clickable

I'm working on a website (my first) that uses WordPress, but I'm tweaking some little things through HTML and CSS code.

I have a bunch of pictures in a grid, that I want to be clickable. All pictures have an overlay that appears when hovering over them with the cursor, and a (permanent) clickable title on top of that.

I would like the image or the overlay to be clickable in its entirety. However, I cannot get it to function properly. I tried to put an `<a href>` and `</a> around the overlay``, but this makes the overlay disappear altogether. If I try the same basic structure (``) in a different spot, it does seem to work, so maybe it has to do with elements 'higher up'.

I'm very new to this, so I might overlook something very basic. I added a piece of HTML and CSS, but since it's part of the WP structure, I'm unable to add all the relevant CSS.

```css
#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  #featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper {
    height: 200px;
  }
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-title {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff5722;
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-title span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 10% 5%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-title span {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-thumbs {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-thumbs .grid-item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-thumbs .grid-item img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-thumbs .category-thumb-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-thumbs .category-thumb-1 img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(28, 224, 43, 0);
  position: absolute;
}

.category-thumb-1:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(28, 224, 43, 0.6);
}

.category-thumb-2:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(28, 224, 43, 0.6);
}

.category-thumb-3:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(28, 224, 43, 0.6);
}

.post-title-1 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.post-title {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 25%;
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-thumbs .category-thumb-2 img,
#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-thumbs .category-thumb-3 img {
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-thumbs .category-thumb-2,
  #featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper .category-thumbs .category-thumb-3 {
    display: block;
  }
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#featured-categories #categories-container .category-wrapper:nth-child(even) .category-title span {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-wrapper category-<?php echo esc_attr( str_replace( ' ', '-', strtolower( esc_html( get_cat_name($cat) ) ) ) ); ?>">
  <div class="category-title">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $cat ) ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_cat_name($cat) ); ?>"><span><?php echo esc_html( get_cat_name($cat) ); ?></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="category-thumbs">
    <div class="category-thumb-1 grid-item">
      <?php if ( isset($thumb[0]) && ($thumb[0] != '') ) :
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb[0], 'large');
           else : ?>
      <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placeholder.png' ); ?>">
      <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="overlay" onclick="window.open('https://localhost/greentravel')" style="cursor: pointer;">
      </div>
      <div class="post-title-1">
        <a href="<?php echo $link[0]?>" <span>
          <?php echo $title[0]?>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category-thumb-2 grid-item">
      <?php if ( isset($thumb[1]) && ($thumb[1] != '') ) :
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb[1], 'large');
          else : ?>
      <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placeholder.png' ); ?>">
      <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
      <div class="post-title">
        <a href="<?php echo $link[1]?>" <span>
          <?php echo $title[1]?>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category-thumb-3 grid-item">
      <?php if ( isset($thumb[2]) && ($thumb[2] != '') ) :
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb[2], 'large');
          else : ?>
      <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placeholder.png' ); ?>">
      <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
      <div class="post-title">
        <a href="<?php echo $link[2]?>" <span>
          <?php echo $title[2]?>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicks require javascript...CSS cannot achieve this. You would have to make the link cover the entire overlay otherwise.

Comment: Hey AmLam, are you able to throw together a codepen of what your problem is? It sounds like you could implement `pointer-events: none` on the base class (i.e. `.overlay` )and then `pointer-events: auto` on the hover state ( `.overlay:hover` ), but I’m not sure I totally understand.

Comment: Hello! Stack Overflow prefers questions which aren't just useful to the person asking them but to everyone else who may find them useful too. May I ask you to *reduce* your code snippets to minimal examples which reproduce your problem? There is a whole lot of CSS rules and markup tags that must have nothing to do with your problem -- why don't you remove them? In fact, if everything boils down to an `a` or `div` element that is supposed to be hoverable and clickable, shouldn't your snippet contain just that element, with a bit of style and script to it?

Comment: I thought that maybe with Html 5 it would be possible to do it without javascript, see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/. In fact, this does work if I make a similar structure on a separate page. However, it doesn't work here, somehow...
That's also why I included the rest of the structure, because I simply don't know where the problem is. If I reduce the entire page to only the <a> and the <div>, it does work, and I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try putting the `<a>` tag inside the `<div>` tag(overlay) and make `<a>` a 'display: block' element. Just try...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried, but to now avail... The <div> keeps disappearing...

Comment: why don't you use javascript and jQuery to make the click work? actually I think I don't get what you mean by clickable.

Comment: I tried, but the same happened: the <div> disappeared.
However, I now set the <a> to display:block, and set height and width to 100%, and that does the trick! Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else looking for answers: At the top of this post, when you hover the OP's gravatar ([@amn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254343/amn); the unicorn img), it does what we're looking for. :-D  It expands, stays open, and the avatar is clickable.

I'm trying to figure out how they're doing this, and I think the magic is in giving it:

- an absolute position
- left, right, top, AND bottom
- high z-index, and
- overflow: hidden